# check input validation [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I was woking on a problem and got stuck and how I should validate a given string input. Here is the original question

[image]

I think my approach is ok but I'm stuck on what to do now.

here is my attempt so far:

```
const solution =(S)=>{
 let validParams = {
   '--count': '--count',
   '--name': '--name',
   '--help': '--help'
 }

let strToTest;
for(k of validParams){

  switch (S.includes(k)) {
    case '--help':
    return 1
    case '--count':
     strToTest = parseInt(S.replace(/--count/g,''))
      return countValidator(strToTest);
    case '--name':
    strToTest = S.replace(/--count/g,'')
      return nameValidator(strToTest);
    default:
      return 1
  }
}
}

const countValidator = (num) =>{
  if(num > 10 && num < 100){
    return 0
  }
}

const nameValidator = (str) =>{
  if(str.length > 3 && str.length < 10){
    return 0
  }
}
```

Here the test cases I saw as well:

```
solution('--count g') // -1
solution('-help name') // -1
solution('--name SOME_NAME --COUNT 10') // 0
solution('--count 44') // 0
```

Comment: validators are always invoked without arguments, how are they supposed to work?

Comment: The parameter to `case` shouldn't be a boolean expression. It's a string that will be compared with `S`. Use `if/else if/else` to perform other kinds of tests.

Comment: @briosheje I completely forgot to add the arguments. I just included it.

Comment: @Barmar I switched the switch case around, still not returning what I expect and im a little confused on why you suggested the `if/else`. can you explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the input into words first, then test the array elements.

You can't return the result of a validator immediately if it succeeds, since you have to keep testing other parameters.

```js
function solution(S) {
  let params = S.split(/\s+/).map(str => str.toLowerCase()); // \s+ matches any amount of whitespace between parameters
  let result = 0;
  if (params.includes('--help')) {
    result = 1;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    switch (params[i]) {
      case "--help":
        break;
      case "--count":
        i++;
        if (i > params.length) {
          result--;
          return result;
        }
        let n = parseInt(params[i]);
        if (isNaN(n) || n < 10 || n > 100) {
          result--;
          return result;
        }
        break;
      case "--name":
        i++;
        if (i > params.length) {
          result--;
          return result;
        }
        let str = params[i];
        if (str.length < 3 || str.length > 10) {
          result--;
          return result;
        }
        break;
      default:
        result--;
        return result;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(solution('--count g')); // -1
console.log(solution('-help name')); // -1
console.log(solution('--name SOME_NAME --COUNT 10')); // 0
console.log(solution('--count 44')) // 0
```

Comment: I see what you mean now. The only think that isn't really clear at the moment is the regex you included when you declared the `params` variable.

Comment: It matches any amount of whitespace between parameters.

Comment: okay, thank you now it makes more sense to me and I understand why splitting the string is needed first